# Firebase Hosting - Homepage vs. Anything Else (empty glob pattern)

Tags: firebase, glob, firebase-hosting

Is there any way to override the default behavior of an **index.html** file in the public folder on Firebase Hosting? Basically, I am trying to take over the BLANK/NULL/EMPTY Glob pattern match so that I can present one page for the ROOT domain, and another for EVERYTHING else. I've tried "/", "*/", and other varieties but nothing works. Also, regardless what paths I specify, the homepage always loads index.html, even if it isn't specified in my firebase.json file...

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/",
        "destination": "/homepage.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "*/",
        "destination": "/homepage.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/app.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want Firebase Hosting to load your index.html, and instead load something else, then simply remove the file from the folder and redeploy.

Comment: If I delete the index.html file, then nothing works as it should.

Comment: Try removing the leading "/" from the destination.  It's probably taking what you have now to mean a file with that exact path, at the root of your filesystem.